# External exception E0434352 при использовании dll, написанной на c#, в приложении на delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, generics, dllimport

Имеется два простых проекта: на delphi и на c#. На delphi написано приложение, которое использует библиотеку, написанную на c#. Цель проектов - проверить возможность передавать интерфейсы через границу dll.
Приложение на delphi содержит:

1. Интерфейсы и процедурный тип TInitFunc:

```
unit uTestApiInterfaces;

{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
{$ALIGN 4}

interface

uses Windows;

type
  plInt32 = LongInt;
  plFloat64 = Double;

  ITestBase = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{DE055014-C9C5-4598-8D23-EB4F649E6A9B}']
    procedure TestBaseFunc(); stdcall;
  end;

  ITest = interface(ITestBase)
  ['{84AFBA2C-C0DB-44E7-AAB4-D34833440D01}']
    procedure TestFunc(); stdcall;
  end;

  ITestGeneric<T> = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{E96329F4-D403-4E24-BCE6-1B78854A6E99}']
    function GetValue(): Int32; stdcall;
  end;

  ITestGenericD = ITestGeneric<plFloat64>;

  IApiApp = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{2CB3BE88-6833-4808-8DE3-CDE041C80F88}']
    function CreateGeneric(out res: ITestGenericD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateTestObj(out obj: ITest): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;


type
  TInitFunc = function(ACore: IApiApp): HRESULT; stdcall;
const
  InitFuncName = 'InitFunc';

implementation

end.
```

2. Реализацию объектов:

```
unit uTestObjects;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, System.SysUtils, uTestApiInterfaces,
  System.Generics.Collections, System.RTLConsts;

type
  TApiApp = class(TInterfacedObject, IApiApp)
  public
    function CreateTestObj(out obj: ITest): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateGeneric(out res: ITestGenericD): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  TObjectTest = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestBase, ITest)
  public
    procedure TestBaseFunc(); stdcall;
    procedure TestFunc(); stdcall;
  end;

  TTestGeneric<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestGeneric<T>)
  public
    function GetValue(): Int32; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

function TApiApp.CreateTestObj(out obj: ITest): HRESULT;
begin
  obj:= TObjectTest.Create();
  obj.TestFunc();
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TApiApp.CreateGeneric(out res: ITestGenericD): HRESULT;
begin
  res := TTestGeneric<Double>.create();
  Result := S_OK;
end;

procedure TObjectTest.TestBaseFunc();
begin
  MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow, 'TestBase', '',0);
end;

procedure TObjectTest.TestFunc();
begin
  MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow, 'Test', '', 0);
end;

function TTestGeneric<T>.GetValue(): Int32;
begin
  Result := 42;
end;


initialization

ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

finalization

end.
```

3. Метод, внутри которого происходит загрузка библиотеки и вызов функции initFunc: TInitFunc :

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fileName: String;
  handle: Cardinal;
  initFunc: TInitFunc;
  ApiApp: IApiApp;
begin
  fileName := 'CSharpDll.dll';
  handle := SafeLoadLibrary(PWideChar(fileName), SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  Win32Check(handle <> 0);
  initFunc := GetProcAddress(handle, InitFuncName);
  Win32Check(Assigned(initFunc));
  ApiApp := TApiApp.Create;
  MessageBox(0, PWideChar('Before init'), '', 0);
  try
    initFunc(ApiApp);
  except on e : Exception do
    MessageBox(0, PWideChar(e.Message), '', 0);
  end;
  MessageBox(0, PWideChar('After init'), '', 0);
end;
```

Библиотека на c# содержит:

1. Интерфейсы, которые соответствуют интерфейсам на delphi:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpDll
{
    using HRESULT = Int32;
    using plInt32 = Int32;
    using plFloat64 = Double;

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ComImport, Guid("DE055014-C9C5-4598-8D23-EB4F649E6A9B")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITestBase
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        void TestBaseFunc();
    }
    
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ComImport, Guid("84AFBA2C-C0DB-44E7-AAB4-D34833440D01")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITest : ITestBase
    {
        #region ITestBase

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        void TestBaseFunc();

        #endregion

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        void TestFunc();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ComImport, Guid("E96329F4-D403-4E24-BCE6-1B78854A6E99")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITestGeneric<T>
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        plInt32 GetValue();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ComImport, Guid("2CB3BE88-6833-4808-8DE3-CDE041C80F88")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IApiApp
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        HRESULT CreateGeneric(out ITestGeneric<plFloat64> res);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
        HRESULT CreateTestObj(out ITest obj);
    }
}
```

2. Экспортируемый метод Init, в котором происходит тестирование работоспособности интерфейсов:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace CSharpDll
{
    using plFloat64 = Double;
    class ExportedFunctions
    {
        [DllExport("InitFunc", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Init(IApiApp ACore)
        {
            //generic - does not work
            ITestGeneric<plFloat64> tg = null; //External exception E0434352
            Int32 h = ACore.CreateGeneric(out tg);
            MessageBox.Show("HRESULT = " + h.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(tg.GetValue().ToString());

            //nongeneric - works
            ITest tt = null;
            Int32 ht = ACore.CreateTestObj(out tt);
            MessageBox.Show("HRESULT = " + ht.ToString());
            tt.TestFunc();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tt);

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ACore);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как заставить generic интерфейсы работать. Ошибка возникает уже в момент объявления интерфейса ITestGeneric (с присваиванием ему null и без). То есть дело даже не доходит до создания объекта в delphi и передачи интерфейса через границу dll.

Comment: Дженерики не экспортируются и не импортируются, никак, вообще, потому что это внутренняя тема CLR. Можно использовать указатели и прочие низкоуровневые фокусы, чтобы протащить динамический набор данных, но прицепить дженерик к экспорту не получится.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за информацию =)